# Using libsvm's predict function. Argument support expected ndarray, int found error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, libsvm

I'm trying to use libsvm to predict probability, and I'm using following command:

```
print(svm.libsvm.predict(x, 3, 'rbf', 3, 0.05, 0.0))
```

It follows from the documentation, args are:

> X: array-like, svm_type: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, kernel: {'linear', 'rbf' ...}
>   degree: int, gamma: float, coef0: float

But it gives me the following error:

> Argument 'support' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got int)

I went through the source code for the wrapper here: 
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/svm/libsvm.pyx

And there is no such documentation on what *support* etc. params are.

Can anyone help me with the usage of this predict function and/or about this error?

Comment: what is the value / type of the x you are passing?

Comment: x is numpy.ndarray type. And it's values are an array of floating points.

Comment: This resource will probably help you; https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8323

Comment: Thanks! I had seen that issue before. The user is using joblib to dump the model and load it, while the file I've is unable to load using joblib. That's why am using the features : x taken from the trained model, and giving it an input. libsvm in python2 works (without using sklearn) but in python3 there's no libsvm package except scikit-learn support.

Comment: But scikit-learns libsvm may not work as the original libsvm in python2.

Comment: Yes, that's why I was testing the predict function. It does not seem to have a way to load model as well. Is there a known way to get support vectors from the model in sklearn?